# Group all row in single row for context data in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to group single user data which is spread in multiple row in mySQL.
I have tried using group by, Joining multiple times all 4 column but not able to achieve.

Below is my Table and Schema

[image]

and I Am trying to get it in the below form as Result

[image]

Can you please help me to form a query in MYSQL

Comment: Someone with your reputation should know to only tag with the appropriate database tags.  I removed the irrelevant tags.

Comment: So you want duplicate rows for each device id?

Comment: @forpas yes. I date wise unique DeviceId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join to the table all the max columns you get after grouping by deviceid:

```
select distinct
    t.date, 
    t.deviceid, 
    g.country, 
    g.affid, 
    g.accountid, 
    g.package
from tablename inner join (
  select 
    deviceid, 
    max(country) country, 
    max(affid) affid, 
    max(accountid) accountid, 
    max(package) package
  from tablename
  group by deviceid
) g on g.deviceid = t.deviceid
```

Comment: Its not giving result as an expected one

Answer (score 1):

You can do aggregation :

```
select deviceid, max(country), max(affid), max(accountid), max(package)
from table t
group by deviceid;
```

**EDIT :** If you are working with higher version then you can use window function :

```
select distinct t.Date, t.deviceid, 
       max(t.country) over (partition by t.deviceid) as country,
       max(t.affid) over (partition by t.deviceid) as deviceid,
       . . . 
from table t;
```

Comment: But this will give duplicate record also with respect to date

Comment: I tried Select  deviceid, eventdate, country, affid, accountid, packageid 
from (
select deviceid, eventdate,
       max(country) over (partition by deviceid) as country,
       max(affid) over (partition by deviceid) as affid,
       max(accountid) over (partition by deviceid) as accountid,
       max(packageid) over (partition by deviceid) as packageid
from npsanalytics.datasample ) as temp
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6 order by deviceid, eventdate
; but is there any other optimized way?

Comment: @AnimeshSinha. . .  Here subquery is not needed & this is the very optimized way if you have a right indexes.

Comment: We cant use Distinct with analytic functions. That's why I have user Subquery.